# Android Studio cant run minsdk

Tags: java, android, run-app

Hi i have this problem with my android project how to fix

minSdk(API22) > device Sdk(API21)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/plJR6.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app `build.gradle` file

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 22 /* this defines the lowest API level your app can run on */
    }
}
```

Please note, as you decrease this number some features might become unavailable.